# How to select a list of values in one column that are available in two different columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tableX as:

```
|-column1-|-column2-|
|   a1    |   b4    |
|   a2    |   b5    |
|   a3    |   b6    |
```

I want to select those values into a single column as result:

```
|-result--|
|   a1    |
|   a2    |
|   a3    |
|   b4    |
|   b5    |
|   b6    |
```

It looks a simple thing to do, but all questions that I look they only concat/merge values into a single column. I need to add them as a "list".

I could use a union clause, like:

```
select column1 as result from tableX
UNION
select column2 as result from tableX
```

but performance will be bad (2x slower) and my SQL statement will be gigantic since tableX is a really complex subquery (bad for maintenance and readability).

<sup>Tagged as MySQL, but I will accept answers for all DBMSs</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend `union all` rather than `union`, so:

```
select column1 as result from tableX
union all
select column2 as result from tableX;
```

`union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  If `tableX` is a table, then this is probably fine.  Although the table is scanned twice, under most circumstances, the table pages will already be in the page cache, so the second scan should be much faster than the first.

If `tableX` is really a complicated view, you can do something a little more efficient:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then column1 else column2 end) as column
from tableX cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

If you still need to remove duplicates, then use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct (case when n.n = 1 then column1 else column2 end) as column
from tableX cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

However, that will probably undo any performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

As [Gordon said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537331/10133679):

> Although the table is scanned twice, under most circumstances, the
>   table pages will already be in the page cache, so the second scan
>   should be much faster than the first.

If the performance of the union is not a problem, I found another solution for a "clean" answer. My problem is not repeating tableX subquery two times because it is a really complex subquery, so I can use a temporary table for this:

```
create temporary table tableX
select * from (...) -- complex query
```

then:

```
select column1 as result from tableX
union all
select column2 as result from tableX;
```